# How to identify text size using image processing?

Tags: image-processing, text-recognition

For a side project at home, I have several pdf documents in "standard" form (White background, black font for text).
For several pages, I have footnotes which are different in size from the main body.
Do you know a way to identify the text block in a document based on the font size?

Comment: you mean a *scanned pdf* ? a vector pdf would already be giving you the text font information...

Comment: A pdf generated from a text editing tool.

Comment: ok, then you should have vector meta data ?

Comment: For the purpose of the exercice, let's suppose that it is not .

Comment: Do you mean "personal project", or are you hiring, firing & promoting folks en mass?  Edit for spelling?

Answer (score 1):

For most fonts, just digitally smear the image horizontally, then look at the height of the resulting gray and white bars.  Assuming typical text the frequency of capitals, descenders and ascenders should be small enough to just contribute a bit of gray.

A more sophisticated method would try to pick out the lines, then find the tips of the ascenders vs. the baseline.  That would be the height of the font in pixels (or whatevers).  Then find the height of each pixel (or whatever) in points, and you have the font height.